# Texture recognition within a specific area in the pic

Tags: opencv, image-processing, textures

I'm new in the texture recognition field, and I would like to know which are the possible ways to approach a texture problem in opencv.

I need to identify the texture within a region in the pic, and tell if it is uniform, homogeneous in the whole area, or not.

More in depth, I need to be able to tell if a possible fallen person is a person (with many different kind of textures) or something wrong like a pillow, or a blanket.

Could anyone suggest a solution, please? 
Is there some already made opencv code to adapt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to far? Please include code. Please update your post and include a sample image and, if possible, another image wheter you have drawn by hand the region you are trying to detect.

Comment: Why would you use texture to identify a person? How would you, for example, distinguish between a person lying on the ground with a fur coat and an animal? They could have the same texture...

Answer (score 5):

Why don't use haralick features? I other words they are called texture features. The base idea is to compute coocurence matrix from given gray-scaled image on base which the haralick features are computed. You can pick between different features like contrast, correlation, entropy etc. which can describe your texture. I guess for the same texture given feature should have the same (similar) value, so that might be the way for distinguishing textures.

Here some links can be helpful:

- [Coocurence matrix tutorial](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/tutorial.htm)
- [Haralik features summary](http://murphylab.web.cmu.edu/publications/boland/boland_node26.html)
- [Coocurence matrix in scikit image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_glcm.html)

So far as I know, there is no implementation of haralick features in opencv, but you can use python with [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) (of course you can use opencv with python if you don't mind using something different than c++).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It sounds good and closed to what I want, but I'm not sure for python since I'm programming a mobile robot and I would like to do everything whit the same kind of implementation. I will look for it in opencv or even how I can implement it by my self..

Comment: It will be nice to implement such feature in opencv. It is not a hard work, if you do implementation for yourself, consider submit your code on opencv group so they can merge your code with library.