# how to use SIFT in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I am learning C++ and OpenCV these days. Given an image, I want to extract its SIFT features. From http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html, we can know that OpenCV 2.4.8 has the SIFT module. 
See here: 
[image]

But I do not know how to use it. Currently, to use SIFT, I need to first call the class SIFT to get a SIFT instance. Then, I need to use `SIFT::operator()()` to do SIFT.

But what is `OutputArray` , `InputArray`,  `KeyPoint`? Could anyone give a demo to show how to use `SIFT` class to do SIFT?

Comment: maybe one of the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection) is helpful ?

Comment: @berak  it is SurfFeatureDetector , not SIFT. But, what I want to use is class SIFT. I show it in the link. Thanks !

Comment: yea, i know. but the procedure is similar

Answer (score 18):

See the example from [Sift implementation with OpenCV 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461148/sift-implementation-with-opencv-2-2)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp> //Thanks to Alessandro

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const cv::Mat input = cv::imread("input.jpg", 0); //Load as grayscale

    cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector.detect(input, keypoints);

    // Add results to image and save.
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::drawKeypoints(input, keypoints, output);
    cv::imwrite("sift_result.jpg", output);

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on OpenCV 2.4.8

Comment: Don't you need `#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"` ?

Answer (score 7):

Update for OpenCV 4.2.0 (don’t forget to link opencv_xfeatures2d420.lib, of course)

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const cv::Mat input = cv::imread("input.jpg", 0); //Load as grayscale

    cv::Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT> siftPtr = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    siftPtr->detect(input, keypoints);

    // Add results to image and save.
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::drawKeypoints(input, keypoints, output);
    cv::imwrite("sift_result.jpg", output);it.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using xfeatures2d version 451 and it has no member SIFT, it has SURF, DAISY, FREAK and a bunch of others but not SIFT :/ is it deprecated or something? Later edit: Apparently it is under `features2d` and available directly as a class in `cv` now: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=sift

Comment: Sorry for two comments, the above link is for version 2.4; for version 4.5 use this link https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d60/classcv_1_1SIFT.html

Answer (score 5):

update for OpenCV3

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp> //Thanks to Alessandro

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const cv::Mat input = cv::imread("input.jpg", 0); //Load as grayscale

    cv::Ptr<cv::SiftFeatureDetector> detector = cv::SiftFeatureDetector::create();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(input, keypoints);

    // Add results to image and save.
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::drawKeypoints(input, keypoints, output);
    cv::imwrite("sift_result.jpg", output);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question for opencv3 but i found [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/). It explains why  SIFT and SURF removed from the default install of OpenCV 3.0 and how to use SIFT and SURF in OpenCV 3.

> The algorithms and associated implementations in `opencv_contrib` are not installed by default and you need to explicitly enable them when compiling and installing OpenCV to obtain access to them.

They are move to `xfeatures2d` library.

`#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>`